# jQuery tmpl gives invalid HTML

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am using jQuery tmpl http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/, and I have `<li id="${id}">` in my HTML source

But when I validate my HTML using the validator, I am getting error "Character $ is not allowed in the value of attribute `id`"

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `How can I solve this issue?` Well, not use `$` in your id's. :)

Comment: @Alex: he uses the $ inside the template, not as part of the id

Answer (score 1):

Place it inside a CDATA-section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$.tmpl( '<li id="${id}">something</li>', myData )
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

In XHTML(assuming you validate as XHTML) `<script/>` is defined as **#P**(arsed)**C**(haracter)**DATA** , so it's contents will be parsed and the error occurs. If you place it inside a CDATA-section, the parser will ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Run validation tests on the final generated HTML, not the templates.

You'll be able to copy it using Firebug, for instance, when viewing your page.